# Zip with filter does not unsubscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component in which I have a `zip` RxJS operator in the constructor:

```js
constructor(
  private apollo: Apollo,
  private sessionService: SessionService,
  private userService: UserService,
  private notificationService: NotificationService,
) {
  this.zip$ = zip(this.userService.user$, this.sessionService.session$)
    .pipe(
      tap((data) => console.log(data)),
      filter(([user, session]) => !!user && !!session),
      take(1)
    )
    .subscribe({
      next: ([user, session]) => {
        this.sessionService.connectUserToSession(
        user!,
        session!,
        UserType.USER
        );
      },
      error: (err) => console.log(err),
      complete: () => console.log('complete')
    });
}
```

My problem is that sometimes the `user, session` values are `null, null`. If that's the case I don't want to do the action in the `subscribe` so I filter that out. The problem this causes is that if the values are filtered the `take()` operator is also not triggered so the `zip` operator is not unsubscribed.

To solve this I've put an `unsubscribe()` in the `ngOnDestroy()`:

```js
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.zip$?.unsubscribe();
  });
}
```

The problem here is that the `unsubscribe()` in the `ngOnDestroy()` is triggered before the `zip()` has finished. If I add a `1000` to the `setTimeOut()` Everything works as expected, but that's not a real solution of course.

Also if I remove the `filter()` operator the component intimidatingly unsubscribes from the `zip()`  if the `user, session` values are `null, null`.

Answer (score 0):

`zip` will only emit an emission from each source one time, so if one emits `null`, but the other emits a valid value, you are essentially filtering out the valid value while "waiting" for the other source to emit a valid value.  Example:

```
zip(a$, b$).pipe(
    filter(([a, b]) => !!a && !!b)
);

// a$: null, a1
// b$: b1

// zip: [null, b1]
```

notice that above code will never emit value `a1` unless `b$` emits a second value!

You could fix this by filtering each source individually before the `zip`:

```
zip(
  a$.pipe(filter(a => !!a)), 
  b$.pipe(filter(b => !!b))
);

// a$: null, a1
// b$: b1

// zip: [a1, b1]
```

---

Alternativly, you could use your original code with `combineLatest` instead of `zip`:

```
combineLatest([this.userService.user$, this.sessionService.session$]).pipe(
    filter(([user, session]) => !!user && !!session),
    take(1)
)
```

Comment: This doesn't really fix my issue with the unsubscribe though. When the component filters out the `null, null` values it doesn't unsubscribe.

Comment: It should if you still include the `take(1)`

Comment: After the first there is nothing to take.

Comment: Are you saying that sometimes you don’t get a valid emission from each source observable?

Comment: Yes, when the component initializes the `user$ and session$` observables both emit a `null` value. Also before I create a user I check if the session exists, and if there's not already a user with that same name. In that case the value would be `null, sessionInfo`.